# Rollback Plugin Version

Tags: plugins

I'm looking to rollback Feedme to a previous version. I can't find any docs or information on Stack Overflow on the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to change the version in your `composer.json` file to the version you want (guessing [4.3.2](https://packagist.org/packages/craftcms/feed-me#4.3.2) if you want the last version) then run `composer update` on the command line.